# Converting a word doc to pdf using Syncfusion DocIO and saving to disk

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, syncfusion

I am using the Syncfusion DocIO library to try and convert a word doc to a pdf.
I am following this [simple example](https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/docio/word-to-pdf):

At the bottom of the example they are doing:

PdfDocument pdfDocument = render.ConvertToPDF(wordDocument);

//Releases all resources used by the Word document and DocIO Renderer objects

```
render.Dispose();

wordDocument.Dispose();

//Saves the PDF file

MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream();

pdfDocument.Save(outputStream);

//Closes the instance of PDF document object

pdfDocument.Close();
```

I need to save the pdf file to the disk instead. How can I take the outputStream and save it to disk? I believe the example is just saving it to memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `FileStream` to write the file to disk:

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    pdfDocument.Save(fs);
}
```

You don't need to use the `MemoryStream` if you don't want to. You can write directly to the `FileStream`.

Comment: If using a word doc as a source and the output should be pdf. Is there a way to go from directly uploading the source to a stream then using the stream to save the output to disk only? Whenever I do using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create)) it creates the file on disk then I can use the steam inside the using. Is there a way to do it without ever creating the file on disk?

Comment: There are examples in the [Syncfusion documentation](https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/docio/loading-and-saving-document#opening-an-existing-document-from-stream) showing how to load a Word document from a stream

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to save the PDF document to a disk which is illustrated in the following code.
https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/loading-and-saving-document?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=asp.net%20core#saving-a-pdf-document-to-file-system

Meanwhile, Word document can also be opened from a disk as a FileStream and converted to PDF document. Kindly refer the following link for code example. 
https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/docio/word-to-pdf?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=asp.net%20core

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Regards,
Dilli babu.